# accessing the functions from external static library

Tags: c++, static, external

I am new to C++ programming in Qt. If you can answer any or part of the questions, that will be great and helpful, thank you.

I am using an external library as static since it is provided only in ".lib" file. I have correctly linked it through the help of stackoverflow website. I also have the header files associated with the library. I included the header file in the main.cpp. I am able to get the function signature by looking at the header file. My question is how do I access the functions from the external library?

For instance, here is a single function that I try to use in main.cpp:

==> QRETURN Quickfind(char *device, unsigned long length);

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]{

// I have declared like this by copying the exact function signature with added extern
extern QRETURN Quickfind(char *device, unsigned long length);
cout << device << " and " << length << endl;
```

}
However, this will show errors that device and length were not declared in this scope.
So, I modify by declaring the parameters before the functions:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]{
char *device = NULL;
unsigned long length = NULL;
extern QRETURN Quickfind(char *device, unsigned long length);
cout << device << " and " << length << endl;
```

}
I was hoping these two parameters will be passed into the function, but apparently they didn't. Also, if I use the function directly after declaration:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]{
char *device = NULL;
unsigned long length = NULL;
extern QRETURN Quickfind(char *device, unsigned long length);
Quickfind(*device, length);
cout << device << " and " << length << endl;
```

}
This will give me undefined reference to 'Quickfind@8' error message.

Can someone show me or give me some hints or help of how to access the functions correctly and its usage from external static library? Thank you.

Comment: Get yourself a good C++ book, you urgently need to read about the very basics of the language. (Sorry if this sounds harsh, but giving you a couple clues so that you can get this to compile and maybe run isn't going to help. C++ is pretty complex, you need to understand what you're writing, and there is no substitute for reading a good book or ten.)

Answer (score 0):

While you have the right general ideas for what you are trying to do, there are some  issues with the way you're doing it.

First, since you are attempting to use an `extern` function, for a function that is in your header file.  To the best of my knowledge, `extern` should only be used if you have a function, class, struct, or global variable, declared in another .cpp file.

Since your function is declared in the header file, you do not need to use `extern`, just include the file like you already have.

Second, when you're creating your variable `length`, you are setting it to `NULL`;  While technically, in most cases, `NULL` is just defined as 0, you should only use `NULL` when declaring null pointers (like your character array).

Third, based on the function signature for Quickfind... As far as I can tell, Quickfind accepts parameters device, and length, and gives you back a QRETURN.  I do not know what exactly Quickfind does, but I am guessing it does not give you a device name, nor a length.

It could possibly give you a name back, but if it does, you'll have to create an array, to put the name in, first.

I do not exactly know what is going on, but please try this:

```
#include <your header file> or "your header file"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]{
    char *device = new char[100];
    unsigned long length = 100;        

    Quickfind(device, length);
    cout << device << " and " << length << endl;
}
```